# PHP Loop Using INT and Strings - How Does This Work?

Tags: php

I posted another question on a similar topic but thought this needed a new question. I have an associative array called cars that is being looped through to produce a string.

The part I don't understand is how the loop works using $i as a key in the if statement when the array is an associative array and the key is a string. If the if statement is saying $i is cars[0], cars[1], cars [2] then how does it cycle through when the keys are actually the strings, like cars[BMW], cars[Mercedes], or cars[AUDI]?

I have been told it is because PHP is loosely typed but it still does not make sense.

Please explain what is going on.

```
if(!isset($_POST["cars"])){
    $carsErr ="Cars must not be left empty";
    $invalidData = true;
} else {
                    
    $cars = array("BMW"=>0,"Mercedes"=>0,"AUDI" =>0,"Trabant"=>0);
                    
    if ($cars == "") {
        $carsErr ="Cars must not be left empty";
        $invalidData = true;
    } else {
                    
        $selectedCars = "";
        for($i=0; $i < count($cars); $i++)
        {
            if(isset($_POST["cars"][$i]))  {
                        
                $cars[$_POST["cars"][$i]] = 1;
                                
                //concatenate all cars in the one string.
                $theCars = strtoupper ($_POST["cars"][$i]);
                switch ($theCars)
                {
                    case "BMW":
                        $selectedCars .= "BMW, "; 
                        break;
                    case "MERCEDES":
                        $selectedCars .= "Mercedes, "; 
                        break;
                    case "AUDI":
                        $selectedCars .= "Audi, "; 
                        break;
                    case "TRABANT":
                        $selectedCars .= "Trabant, "; 
                        break;
                    default:
                        $selectedCars .= $_POST["cars"][$i].", ";
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it using `$i` on the `$_POST["cars"]` values (`$_POST["cars"][$i]`)?

Comment: The ```$_POST["cars"]```  keys are from an associative arrray and the keys are strings. The values are all zero after the array function sets them. As far as I understand it.

Comment: you're counting your $cars array and looping while $i(0) < count($cars) then $i++, inside the loop you use $i to check if is set $_POST['cars'][$i] (for example $_POST['cars'][2] = 'BMW' ). If is set put 1 as to $cars['BMW']. Then strtoupper($_POST["cars"][$i]) if value $_POST["cars"][2] is 'bmw' it becomes 'BMW' and then the switch. That's it ...

Comment: as @NigelRen pointed out $i is used on $_POST["cars"], not $cars

Comment: What is it called when you use ```[$i]``` in square brackets after the ```$_POST["cars"]```? Is that  setting an index of the array cars? Just not sure about that syntax.

Comment: Consider the following code: `$_POST["cars"] = ["BMW", "VW", "Honda"]`. The `cars` index of the `$_POST` array stores another array. So by calling `$_POST["cars"][0]`, you are first accessing the `cars` index of `$_POST`, and then the index `0` of `$_POST["cars"]`. It's called a nested array, or multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes with what I have learned since my original post.

The $_POST[cars] array would look something like this:

```
$_POST[cars] = array (
    [0] => BMW,
    [1] => Mercedes,
    [2] => Audi,
    [3] => Trabant
);
```

And the $cars array would look like this:

```
$cars = array (
    BMW => 0,
    Mercedes => 0,
    Audi => 0,
    Trabant => 0
);
```

So it indexes through the `$_POST[cars]` array using `[0],[1],[2]` etc. with the $i in the for loop.

Then it gets to `$cars[$_POST["cars"][$i]] = 1;` where it references the `0` of the $cars array for each item in the `$_POST` array using the multidimensional array syntax. This is what I didn't get before.

it uses the `isset` function to check if each of the post array variables is set in the form. Then it sets each to `1` or leaves it as `0` using the `$cars[$_POST["cars"][$i]] = 1;` assignment.

There still seems to be one thing missing though and that is what is the `isset` function using. I assume it is `0` or `null` or `1` if a checkbox is checked. But that must not be part of `POST` array but a seperate item in the `POST` array itself.